# how to put encoding on xlsxwriter with python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I want to write to excel files from textfiles and have centimeter square string in it like this picture

[image]

and when i run the the code it shows error like this

[image]

So i put an encoding but still not working like this

```
spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename[:-4] + '.xlsx')
workbook.encoding="latin1"
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Original data')
```

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 4):

```
sheet.write(rowx, colx, value.decode('latin1'))
```